# Avoid Storing Keys in Key-Value Store by Replacing the Key with 128-bit Murmur3 Hash

Tags: data-structures, search-algorithms, hash

I want to develop LRU key-value data store and in that wanted to get rid of space to store the key itself. Instead wanted to store a 128 bit murmur hash. The structure of data-store that I want to explore is similar to CPU k-way set-associative caches.

So the algorithm I want to pursue is -

1. Compute a murmur 3 hash for given key.
2. Using the hash find the set where the data should be stored.
3. Let us say the cache is 4 way associative, therefore I have four slots where I can store the data.
4. If the slots are already full I kick out the one earliest used.
5. I store the hash in-place of key itself. But I understand that collisions are possible.
6. Banking on avalanche effect (this is risky and hence the question), I am assuming that if the two strings differ only by a little, the hash will be different. However, two 'largely' different strings may still collide.
7. Since the hash is of fixed size (128 bit) let us say, I can get rid of `memcmp()` of the whole key length, which is 256-byte long (max) in my system.
8. I store just the hash, and compare hash to the stored hash (which acts like TAG in the cache). In case the two strings collide, I also store few bytes (say 15-20 bytes) along with their offsets which needs to be compared only if hash values match.

Assumed benefit of this is -

1. no need to store keys and hence huge space can be saved
2. avoid `memcmp()` on full length of the key, and the hash which is calculated once is used both for matching keys and identifying slots.

I want evaluation and review of this method and if there are ways on we can solidify this. I understand that comparison of bytes at some offsets may not be the reliable way. Are there any other existing methods which avoid storing of keys?

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate place to ask this question. It strikes me as more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se], although I don't hang out there so I don't really know what their criteria are. From a theoretical point of view, hash collisions are always possible, and if the consequences are sufficiently severe then saying "it's very unlikely" may not be a sufficient safeguard. From a more practical POV, memcmp will practically never take more time than a single-word comparison precisely because strings in the same hash set typically differ in the first few bytes.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the alert. +1

Comment: @rici "because strings in the same hash set typically differ in the first few bytes." ... This is some thing I was not aware of. Can you please point me to any reference on this?

Comment: It's a simple consequence of how hashing has to work if it is going to do a good job. It's not saying anything different from your point 6; similar keys have different hashes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonable approach.  To make it more solid, I suggest replacing Murmur3 with a cryptographic hash, such as SHA256. Then we get a kind of guarantee: it is believed to be intractable to find a collision for the hash function.  In other words, for all engineering purposes, we expect you will never in your lifetime encounter a pair of inputs with the same SHA256 hash. So, you can ignore the risk of collisions.  There's no need to store an extra 15-20 bytes -- just rely on the SHA256 hash.  As a side benefit, the SHA256 hash is only 256 bits long, not 256 bytes, so it'll save you additional space.

Comment: Thank you +1. I wanted to use SHA256, however felt that it is computationally very expensive than murmur3. In absence of any other solution, that is where I am heading to. Good to know that someone else thinks that this is doable.